how to style the date picker icon in firefox
I'm trying to hide the datepicker icon from Firefox input field and add my own icon but none of the CSS rules I'v tried works.
I'm adding a padding to the right to prevent the textfield going under my icon (for consistency with my other input fields), but this shifts the default icon.
The icon also has a default opacity effect on hover that I'd like to remove but no CSS selector/rules seem to be working.


input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  aspect: none color: transparent;
}
<label for="Data di consegna" class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap text-gray-light-2">Delivery Date</label>






the -webkit vendor prefix is not for firefox.

So, like @Adam, I had added a Stack Snippet, but there are two problems preventing it from doing anything; there's no <input type="date"> in the HTML  and the CSS is malformed: there's a semicolon missing between none and color. (Also, the for on label is pointing to three separate elements, since IDs cannot have spaces).

Its not really a good idea to try to do this, as there are no guarantees this will work or even remain working. Tell your designers: "no, dont mess with default inputs".

try this:


input[type="date"] {
  appearance: none; /* Hide the default date icon in Firefox */
  -moz-appearance: none; /* Hide the default date icon in Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hide the default date icon in WebKit browsers */
  padding-right: 30px; /* Make room for the custom icon */
  position: relative;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none; /* Hide the default date icon in WebKit browsers */
}

input[type="date"]::after {
  content: '\1F4C5'; /* Unicode for calendar icon */
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray; /* Adjust the color as needed */
}
<label for="delivery-date" class="text-sm whitespace-nowrap text-gray-light-2">Delivery Date</label>
<input type="date" id="delivery-date" name="delivery-date">




You have to be careful about using ::before and ::after pseudo elements because <input> is not a container. See this answer on stackoverflow.

Doens't seems to be working (also in the snippet) it's not working under Firefox.
